# python yaml load formatted string

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to load yaml that contains python formatted strings, e.g. `test: {formatted_string}`. This would allow me to format the string using `dictionary["test"].format(formatted_string="hello yaml")`, but when I load the yaml, it's automatically converted to `{'test': {'formatted_string': None}}` instead of `{'test': '{formatted_string}'}`.

There are dozens of .yaml files that are already formatted in this way.

I don't see this in the pyyaml docs or anywhere on SO.

Code in full for clarity:

```
import yaml


data = """
test: {formatted_string}
"""
d1 = yaml.load(data)
print(d1)
# {'test': {'formatted_string': None}}

d2 = {"test": "{formatted_string}"}
print(d2)
# {'test': '{formatted_string}'}

d2["test"] = d2["test"].format(formatted_string="hello yaml")
print(d2)
# {'test': 'hello yaml'}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{` character in YAML (as in JSON) introduces a dictionary. That is this:

```
a_dictionary:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Is completely equivalent to:

```
a_dictionary: {key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

So when you write...

```
test: {formatted_string}
```

...the YAML parser things you are introducing a dictionary, and that it has a single key (`formatted_string`) and no value. If you want to use a `{` as part of a YAML *value* you need to quote it:

```
test: "{formatted_string}"
```

Compare:

```
>>> yaml.safe_load('test: {formatted_string}')
{'test': {'formatted_string': None}}
>>> yaml.safe_load('test: "{formatted_string}"')
{'test': '{formatted_string}'}
```

In general, if you always quote your YAML strings your life will be easier :).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Unfortunately, there are already dozens of yaml files that are formatted without quotes. Is there any straightforward way around that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question...but if you're going to use a special character like `{` in your YAML, you need to quote it. There's not really a workaround for that.